# How to use geofirex inside google cloud functions

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, geofirex

I have a use case where I need to use [geofirex](https://github.com/codediodeio/geofirex) library inside Google Cloud Functions. The init function of the library expects FirebaseApp instance. Is it possible to initialise it inside cloud functions in order to query firestore database using firebase-admin?

What i tried..

functions > src > index.ts

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();
admin.firestore().settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true});


// Init GeoFireX
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import * as geofirex from 'geofirex';
const geoFire = geofirex.init(firebase);

exports.geofenceUserNotifications = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if(!req || !req.body || !req.body.length || !req.body[0].latitude || !req.body[0].longitude || !req.body[0].uid || !req.body[0].userFcmToken){
    // end function with 401 status
    res.status(401).send('Authentication required.');
  }

  const uid = req.body[0].uid;
  const userFcmToken = req.body[0].userFcmToken;
  const latitude = req.body[0].latitude;
  const longitude = req.body[0].longitude;
  const field = 'position';

  geoFire.collection('users').setPoint(uid, field, latitude, longitude).then(result => {
    res.end('User geoPoint updated!');
  }).catch( err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.end('error when update user geo point!');
  });

});
```

functions > package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "firebase": "^5.10.1",
    "geofirex": "0.0.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.8.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

No error when deploy but when call geofenceUserNotifications function i get this error:

```
TypeError: app.firestore is not a function
    at new GeoFireCollectionRef (/user_code/node_modules/geofirex/dist/index.cjs.js:1465:24)
    at GeoFireClient.collection (/user_code/node_modules/geofirex/dist/index.cjs.js:1639:16)
    at exports.geofenceUserNotifications.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/lib/index.js:2197:13)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the problem solved as following:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
admin.firestore().settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true});

// Init GeoFireX
const geofirex = require('geofirex');// <-- Use require Instead of import geofirex
import { get } from 'geofirex';
const geoFire = geofirex.init(admin); // <-- admin not admin.app()
```

**Then**

```
exports.geofenceUserNotifications = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

  //setPoint (id, field, lat, lng)
  geoFire.collection('users').setPoint(uid, field, latitude, longitude).then(result => {
    res.end('User geo point is updated!');
  }).catch( err => {
      res.end('error when update user geo point');
      return;
  });
});
```

**And geoFireX works fine.**

but now I faced other problem with geoFireX query.
I tried get nearby items but geoFireX returns `Observable<object[]>` and it's not work within cloud functions.

**I tried use [get()](https://github.com/codediodeio/geofirex#promises-with-get) by geoFireX:**

```
const query = geoFire.collection('places', queryRef).within(center, radius, field);
const nearbyPlaces = await get(query); // await query.pipe(operators.first()).toPromise();
```

but unfortunately it does not work. and I get the following error:

> Error: Argument "onNext" is not a valid function.
>       at Validator.(anonymous function).values [as isFunction] (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/validate.js:99:27)
>       at Query.onSnapshot (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1524:25)
>       at Observable._subscribe (/srv/node_modules/geofirex/dist/index.cjs.js:1597:33)
>       at Observable._trySubscribe (/srv/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:44:25)
>       at Observable.subscribe (/srv/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:30:22)
>       at MapOperator.call (/srv/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/map.js:32:23)
>       at Observable.subscribe (/srv/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:25:31)
>       at Object.subscribeToResult (/srv/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToResult.js:12:23)
>       at CombineLatestSubscriber._complete (/srv/node_modules/rxjs/internal/observable/combineLatest.js:76:46)
>       at CombineLatestSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (/srv/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:78:18)

Answer (score 2):

**-- Maybe this is the complete solution --**

**Two Steps:-**

> 1. Adding Geopoint and Geohashes into firestore
> 2. Query with geopoint data

**Step-1 Solution:**
For this, you've to add firebase-admin sdk and configure the geofirex with geofirex.init(admin). 
Ex:

```
const geofirex = require('geofirex');// <-- Use require Instead of import geofirex
import { get } from 'geofirex';
const geo = geofirex.init(admin); // <-- admin not admin.app()
```

now you can store your Geopoint and Geohashes like this:-

```
const point = geo.point(40.1, -119.1);
```

Store this into database by using firestore.

**Step-2 Solution:**
For this, you've to use firebase web sdk to configure the geofirex. Otherwise, you cannot be able to query from your firestore database! 
Ex:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: API_KEY_HERE,
    authDomain: DOMAIN_HERE,
    databaseURL: FIREBASE_REALTIME_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: MEASUREMENT_ID
  };
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

import geofirex = require('geofirex');// <-- Now, use import Instead of require('geofirex')
const geo = geofirex.init(firebase.app()); // <-- firebase or, firebase.app()
```

You can get **firebaseConfig** from your firebase console web sdk setup. Just copy and paste that! ;)
Now you can query your firestore geopoint like this:-

```
router.get('/expert', (req, res, next) => {
    const radius = req.query.radius
    const lat = req.query.lat
    const lng = req.query.lng
    const field = 'position'

    geo.collection('ex-pending').within(geo.point(lat, lng), radius, field).subscribe(snap => {
        res.status(200).send(snap)
    })

})
```

That's it! :D

Comment: One more thing! If you face any issue with the "subscribe" method of geofirex, then you ca use this for querying:

`const promise = geo.collection('ex-pending').within(geo.point(lat, lng), radius, field)
    const snap = await get(promise)`


this is the async await method instead of RxJs.

Comment: this shows an example for a node js backend not cloud functions. Theyre very similar but in my case i am using the https.onCall method and this doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 1):

On second inspection, it seems that the [Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js *does* have the concept of a FirebaseApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.html#.app). You might want to try passing `admin.app()` into GeofireX to initialize it.

<strike>Within Cloud Functions you're using the [Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node), which doesn't have the concept of a `FirebaseApp`.</strike>

From a quick scan it looks like GeofireX was only made to be used with the client-side JavaScript SDK of Firebase. You might want to [file a feature request on its repo](https://github.com/codediodeio/geofirex/issues), or even better a PR. :)

Comment: Thanks @Frank for your help. i tried `const geoFire = geofirex.init(admin.app());` not work but i do that by an other way, first `const geofirex = require('geofirex');` then `const geoFire = geofirex.init(admin.app());` and i think it's work but now i faced other problem when call function i get `TypeError: this.app.firestore.GeoPoint is not a constructor
    at GeoFirePoint.get [as geoPoint] (/user_code/node_modules/geofirex/dist/index.cjs.js:1390:20)
    at GeoFirePoint.get [as data] (/user_code/node_modules/geofirex/dist/index.cjs.js:1411:31)
    at GeoFireCollectionRef.setPoint (/u....`

Comment: Yeah... while GeoFireX may be able to be used in your context, it seems more focused on web. You're going to have to dig into the GeoFireX source code for that stack trace to learn what caused it. That's what I did to get to my revised answer above, which apparently solved your first problem. It's a matter of seeing what the stack trace points at, and working backwards from there.

Comment: i traced GeoFireX source code but I could not determine the cause of the problem :( the line at `node_modules/geofirex/dist/index.cjs.js:1390` is: `return new this.app.firestore.GeoPoint(this.latitude, this.longitude);`

Comment: TypeError: this.app.firestore.GeoPoint is not a constructor at GeoFirePoint.get can be resolved by calling .data at the end